# Ionic Push FCM iOS - get device token (not firebase token)

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, apple-push-notifications, token, cordova-plugin-fcm

when I use [FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging)](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm/) `cordova plugin` on iOS, I get this token:

```
c-NtgjPB8Rg:APA91bEk0bvwec5tGjzCYQ_0I2axwpFmuRJ1JRUpHwdcTkVV1J1AR_Xb3p7qYp68il0y_TmiJ4ecQYDQdCFDLwzA-KALA_I7Q2tUOW2zszsDA0lPD8tvo0IlRYhf1Z5KwhR5u6h02z2w
```

but it should be in this format:

```
3b985a82 451ef20d f6f6e481 8de19a3d 1855e6de daf09915 e9b8a42b 3c05c79c
```

I'm using this method:

```
this.fcm.getToken().then(token => { /*saving token here*/});
```

Am I receiving some kind of **Firebase** token? How can I get **APNS** token?

Comment: use ionic push to get a ios apns token ref- https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/

Comment: I was trying it for a week with no success on macOS. I am not able to build it on mac because of error that Cocoa can not be run with sudo and without sudo I have no permissions. So I was forced to move to the FCM plugin instead. Its probably my environment froblem but I was unable to figure it out.

Comment: reinstall your platform without using sudo

Answer (score 0):

The token you got looks correct, it is very similar to the perfectly working tokens I get. It should not have any blank spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getAPNSToken() function:

```
 this.fcm.getAPNSToken().then(token => { /*saving token here*/});
```

and you will validate the platform too:

```
   if (this.platform.is('android')){
      token= await this.fcm.getToken();
    }

    if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
      token= this.fcm.getAPNSToken()
    }
```